Two foliation atlases define the same foliation iff they induce the same partition
Let $A_1$ and $A_2$ be two different (maximal) foliation atlases on a smooth manifold $M$. I want to show, that they induce a different partition of $M$.
So far I managed to proof the following:
Let $(U,\phi) \in A_1 \setminus A_2$. Because $A_2$ is maximal, there exists $(V,\psi) \in A_2$ such that the change of charts diffeomorphism doesn't globally look like $(x,y) \mapsto(g(x,y),h(y))$. Therefore, one can find an $y \in \mathbb{R}^q$ with
$$ 
\psi \circ \phi^{-1}\big(\left(\mathbb{R}^{n-q} \cap W\right) \times \{y\}\big) = \big(\mathbb{R}^{n-q} \cap \tilde{W}\big) \times D
$$
and $W,\tilde{W} \subset \mathbb{R}^{n-q}$ and $|D|>1$. Therefore it is
$$
\psi^{-1} \circ \psi \circ \phi^{-1}\big(\left(\mathbb{R}^{n-q} \cap W\right) \times \{y\}\big) = \psi^{-1}\big((\mathbb{R}^{n-q} \cap \tilde{W}) \times D\big).
$$
This only tells me, that the corresponding leaf has to consist of multiple disjoint plaques in $V$. But how can I conclude now, that the induced partitions are different?
NOTE: I don't have many tools available at this time which I would be able to use. I only have some basic definitions regarding foliations. Your help would be much appreciated.

What is your definition of partition.

A Partition of M is a subset $F \subset \mathcal{P}(M)$ such that every point   is contained in exactly one set $U\in F$.
